# How can I post a text string having hyperlink to some URL on the facebook wall

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an application that wants me to design a functionality of posting an audio file to the wall and also there is a message along with the audio file. I have successfully posted/shared the audio file to the wall but now I want some text of my message should have a hyperlink to some URL.

Somebody plz help to get ou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the link as an attachment to the wall post.
Sample C# code : http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=235649&ANCHOR

You can find similar code for the language of your choice. Just google it.